Request exception: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
I am making a Python app to fetch data from my website (which is written in PHP) as a stream.
main.py
import requests
from sseclient import SSEClient

def get_sse(url):
    try:
        # Make the request to the SSE endpoint
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        
        # Create an SSEClient instance with the response stream
        client = SSEClient(response)
        
        # Process each event received
        for event in client.events():
            print(f"Received event: {event.data}")
    
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Request exception: {e}")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Connection closed by user")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sse_url = 'http://mywebsite.com/endpoint.php'  # Replace with your SSE endpoint
    get_sse(sse_url)

endpoint.php
<?php
// chat.php

// Path to the file that stores the latest message
$messageFile = 'latest_message.txt';

// Function to handle message sending
function handleSendMessage() {
    global $messageFile;

    // Read the incoming message from POST data
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? trim($_POST['message']) : '';

    // Validate message content (basic validation)
    if ($message !== '') {
        // Store the message in a file
        file_put_contents($messageFile, $message);
        echo "Message sent!";
    } else {
        echo "No message provided!";
    }
}

// Function to handle message receiving via SSE
function handleReceiveMessage() {
    global $messageFile;

    // Set headers for SSE
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    // Function to get the latest message from the file
    function getLatestMessage() {
        global $messageFile;
        if (file_exists($messageFile)) {
            return file_get_contents($messageFile);
        }
        return '';
    }

    // Initial message
    $lastMessage = getLatestMessage();

    // Loop to send updates to the client
    while (true) {
        // Get the latest message
        $currentMessage = getLatestMessage();

        // If there's a new message, send it
        if ($currentMessage !== $lastMessage) {
            echo "data: $currentMessage\n\n";
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            $lastMessage = $currentMessage;
        }

        // Sleep for a while to prevent CPU overload
        usleep(100000); // 0.1 seconds
    }
}

// Determine the type of request and handle accordingly
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    handleSendMessage();
} elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    handleReceiveMessage();
} else {
    echo "Invalid request method!";
}
?>

As you may notice, the PHP works for the sender and the receiver, but I don't think that should cause this following issue:
"Request exception: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"
There is no CORS, or other kind of security that I know of, but if you strongly believe there is, please tell me. It works fine when doing it in my website itself:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SSE Test</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS not needed */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SSE Test</h1>
    <div id="messages"></div>

    <script>
        // Replace with your SSE endpoint
        const sseUrl = '/endpoint.php';

        // Create a new EventSource instance
        const eventSource = new EventSource(sseUrl);

        // Function to handle incoming messages
        eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
            const messageContainer = document.getElementById('messages');
            const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
            messageElement.className = 'message';
            messageElement.textContent = `Received message: ${event.data}`;
            messageContainer.appendChild(messageElement);
            messageContainer.scrollTop = messageContainer.scrollHeight; // Auto-scroll to the bottom
        };

        // Function to handle errors
        eventSource.onerror = function(event) {
            const messageContainer = document.getElementById('messages');
            const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
            messageElement.className = 'message';
            messageElement.textContent = `Error: ${event.type}`;
            messageContainer.appendChild(messageElement);
            messageContainer.scrollTop = messageContainer.scrollHeight; // Auto-scroll to the bottom
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Is there something I am doing wrong? Why does it work on my website but not on my Python file?

Sounds like a CORS exception to me. It will always work on the same site as it's the same origin (unless one app is on a subdomain).  You Python code has no generic exception so the error may be hiding in plain sight.
Also, not sure how Python handles the event cycle, but shouldn't you have all your handling set up first, then make the request?
Also, if your Python code runs in the browser, check the Network tab of the dev tools in your browser and it will tell you what's happening. Ideally de-complicate the issue, maybe make a direct call from a Python shell and see what happens.

Sorry for the late reply (I thought I would be emailed). My HTML and PHP are on the same site and my Python is running on my computer. If a browser running on my computer correctly works with the HTML, why can't the Python do so too? And I don't think CORS applies to this because the Python is running locally and should not have an origin

I'm being a bit of a hypocrite helping here as I think this collective should be for PHP only, but I'm trying to be a better person, so here goes.
Add a header to keep the connection open to the request: headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive'}, then update to: response = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers, timeout=60)
On the server-side (PHP), just emit somethign, don't worry about the SSE, validate the connection to isolate the problem. If you get a response, move on. Isolate and move on just like tracing a circuit problem. Something like: if (!empty($_POST)) die($_POST);
